# How would a species in a world where magic is banned also ban Science?

Tags: internal-consistency, society, warfare, politics

The people in my world who can't use magic are at war with the people who can use magic. Both groups used to be at peace before political and global conflict started, and long before they were at war the global population all agreed that science was a great taboo due to past warfare between science and magic, and agreed to not use the scientific method. (Although very small groups of people still use science in secret).

Now that the people who can't use magic are at war with the people who can, they are at a great disadvantage, becuase they can't use magic nor science, and can only use magical items, "god-blessed" artifacts, technology (from all continents) between the years 1000-1500 and a wide variety of soldiers like medieval knights, samurai, roman soldiers and etc, but they can't advance their technology.

In rare cases people can be born with superhuman strength, regeneration slow but can grow back a limb within a year, perception and the ability to adapt to their environment and get stronger slowly.

Whilst the people who can use magic can control the weather, energy, elements, objects around them, buff people and themselves and to a very small degree bend time and space to teleport very short distances there are more things they can do with magic which is too much to cover here. They can also use the technology the people who can't use magic use but no magic user can be born superhuman.

The war is at a stalemate due to the superhumans being born, so how do I make sure that the people in this world don't turn to science to win the war?

Extra Info about the world and its inhabitants:

- fantasy setting
- atypical fantasy monsters like dragons and goblins but there are also unconventional ones like blobs of flesh teeth and faces, human sized cyclops monsters that kills you then turns you into one of them and flying whales with crying baby faces which drink clouds
- Other species and demi-humans who have human intelligence example: atlanteans, elves, dryads, dwarfs, tree-people, lizard-people of multiple types, fur-humans of multiple types and giants of multiple types maybe more if i forgot any
- Science has been banned for 70k years
- space exploration with magic is not possible

Comment: you can't really _ban science_, as this effectively means banning "trying if stuff works or not and learning from the result". better just ban specific science/engineering categories, like metallurgy or alchemy. and keep in mind that "trying if a magic spell works" is, technically, science as well.

Comment: Banned for *seventy thousand years*? To put that number in perspective, neanderthals only went extinct about *forty* thousand years ago. 70,000 years ago there was no "science" and technology was at the level of stone tools.

Comment: A *species* is a category in biology. A species cannot ban anything, because a species is not a category in politics. Only a state can ban something. And since there is a war, it follows that there are at least two states. One of them will support everything which the other had banned...

Comment: how does a country or state that banned both science and magic prosper? Suppose there is a plague that threaten the entire population, without magic to wish away the disaster or science to teach them to wash their hands they are going to be wiped out.

Comment: In terms of banning at least some very important science, get back to me after the 2024 elections in the US, especially if Covid is still around or some other major disease pops up to cause problems.

Comment: Science is not one specific thing. It's not even necessarily any specific process. It's a culmination of generations of trial and error and continual learning. Not sure how you ban learning without ruining everything.

Comment: @coppereyecat There is a difference between learning because you were doing something, and learning because you were studying something.  A blacksmith might have a batch of iron ore that got rained on.  He does not want to wait for it to dry out so he throws it in his fireplace to dry.  He pulls it out, and uses it, and low and behold, he gets a better iron out of it; so, he proceeds to always fire dry his ore first.  He never set out to make better steel, and does not understand that he is really burning the sulpher and phosphorous out.

Comment: Studying metallurgy would involve deliberately experimenting by burning, quenching, and mixing iron with everything you can think of to try to find a better way to make your steel, or to better understand its composition.  So, you can do the one without the other.

Comment: I think you would get better answers if you define science and the scientific method. Please also note that the scientific method (especially the thing that we are taught in school) is a rather late invention. It did not exist in 1000-1500. In our world, modern scientific enquiry was only started to be developed in the 16th century. And it took a long time for it to become what science uses today.

Comment: I'm not sure the magic/science dichotomy makes any sense. In a world where magic is real, it's just another natural phenomena, so why aren't the "scientists" studying and using it?

Comment: If someone gets 2 of their best horses and breed them because they know the baby horse will also likely have the desired traits present in the parents, that's science. If a group uses the stars to determine when will be the best time to plant their crops, that's science. If you change a spell because you find out the change makes it better, science again. Unlike magic, science isn't some superpower that can be used or not, it's a process that involves any and all changes of behavior towards reaching a certain goal or optimizing something. For all intents and purposes octopuses use science.

Comment: Any animal that can learn from its behavior and learn how to optimize an activity through trial and error is in a way practicing science. To enforce science not being used you'd need everyone to regress into a purely instinctive state that makes little to no use of any learned activities/behaviors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several ideas, unfortunately can't comment yet so I'm throwing it all here:

### Science refers to something specific

Maybe what these people call science is actually a something linked to magic like alchemy? This gives you a chance to discern a line between 'normal every-day science' (described in @L.Dutch's answer) and alchemy.

For instance, you can have the people consider metallurgy as alchemy, which could explain why the people can't advance their technology past what they have already. However, making cheese could not be considered alchemy, so its fine to do.

### Faith in a god

You didn't say if there were dieties in your fantasy setting, but this could help. Another counterpart to magic in your world could be faith in and prayer to an all powerful diety. Not sure you want to go that way, but this could explain why the non-magic people have a fighting chance.

Perhaps your superhumans are also a blessing from their god... or perhaps the product of a ritual.

To keep the people from going to science, you can also have a concept of purity in their religion - this could keep them from performing the rituals that they need to fight off the magic users. Both science and magic could make a person ritually impure. For science specifically, you could say that the scientific method corrupts a person's perspective so that they can't think about their god properly (or pray properly, or perhaps it damages their faith... etc). Much could also depend on what their god does or values.

### A Tainted/Blocked Origin

The origins of the scientific method could have come from a demon or some evil man. Or even perhaps the first scientists all died in some terrible accident or tried to learn necromancy or something. Or perhaps some mysterious extra-dimensional beings stop science that's being practiced in open for unknown reasons.

Your people could see the merits of using the scientific method to get an edge in battle, however, because its tainted no one wants to go there. This would give you the opportunity to have extensive debates or riots or something in your country of non-magic users.

Answer (score 10):

You can use science without knowing it's science.

Men made bread, cheese, wine, beer well before understanding the science behind it. Men selectively bred horses, cows and sheep well before understanding the genetic behind it. One can empirically find that doing A then B will happen.

This is also how superstition got engrained in our brain: I danced and then it rained, this mean that by dancing I can make rain. Call me the man of the rain!

Answer (score 4):

## Sufficiently advanced devices inhibit magic.

Magic, unknown to the people, relies in the subconscious beliefs of the population. Sufficiently advanced technical materials tend to imbue belief in their operation, and draw in magic to power themselves.

This makes them operate better and gain some degree of sentience, and has lead to several terrible machine revolutions.

This also tends to inhibit both superhuman and normal magical powers, and so such technologies are forbidden for the danger they hold. No one wants a cold metal mind blast furnace rampaging through people.

Answer (score 4):

/how do I make sure that the people in this world don't turn to science to win the war?/

**They promptly lose.**

The nonmagic users are terribly outmatched.  Their only advantage is the superhumans who somehow are on the nonmagic user side.

The magic users coopt the superhumans.  They ask "why, given your powers, are you allying yourselves with these ordinary folks?  You should rule them with us.  Help us talk some sense into these folks because in addition to their tragic normalness they are tragically stupid to be picking fights with magic users.  These folks are risking being wiped out by magic and that does not seem right.  Help us help them see reason."

The nonmagic users will not turn to science or anything else to win the war.  They will lose the war.  They should consider themselves lucky to be left alive.

Comment: Exactly this - wielders of powerful magic are so advantaged, that there can't really be a conflict with the non-magic people. Even relatively limited magic like in Sanderson's Mistborn series (especially second trilogy) give devastating advantage over normal people.

Answer (score 3):

**Promote the ignorance that does not make any distinction between the two.**

“Any sufficiently advanced technology is indistinguishable from magic.”
OR
“Any sufficiently advanced magic is indistinguishable from technology.”

Comment: It's deeper than that.  In our world, there's no need to ban magic because *magic doesn't work*.  In OP's world, magic does work, magic users manifest effects on the physical world.  Then the study of magic, like the study of any cause and effect, is.... a *science*.

Answer (score 3):

### The Non-Magic Users Already have a significant technological advantage

Since all civilizations are somewhere between that of 1000 and 1500, just put these two civilizations at either extreme. The civilization with magic has a lot less reason to invest time in learning crafts like blacksmithing, masonry, carpentry, etc.  As a result all of the stuff they do craft is sub par. A lot of really important advancements in metallurgy, weapon design, and tactics occurred in this 500 year time span, and these advancements were not the result of the scientific method, just generation after generation of dedicated craftsmen talking among themselves about what does and does not work.  Because of this minor distinction between superior science and superior craftsmanship, the non-magic society does not need the scientific method to be more technologically advanced.

### What Advantages do the non-magic users have?

- **Better steel:**  In 1000CE, steel was typically low-carbon steel with significant sulphur & phosphorous contamination.  By 1500CE the practice of burning the sulphur & phosphorous out of ore before refining had become almost universal, and they replaced bloomery steel with reduced crucible steel which gave them much better control over carbon content. They also significantly improved thier tempering methods allowing them to make flexible spring steel. This makes every steel object they make significantly tougher than anything the magic guys can make.
- **Better Weapon and Armor Designs:** In 1000CE, a typical knight armor wore a shirt of chainmail that only went down to the knees and elbows, and most helmets were open faced.  Most weapons were relatively blunt because overly acute points would easily break due to the quality of the steel.  Most people who were not knights worn cloth armor.  By 1500CE, knights typically wore head to toe plate armor with very few gaps to exploit.  Their armor distributed impact much better making them far harder to kill using blunt force weapons like a warhammer.  They carried much more acutely tipped weapons designed to exploit the gaps in armor and punch right through chainmail.  And they also had arbalests with bodkin tipped bolts.  This meant that they could quickly train up large peasant forces to be crossbowmen with ranged weapons that would go straight through chainmail.  It was also far more common for rank-and-file soldiers to be equipped with at least partial metal armor that would have been comparable to what the knights 500 years before would have used.
- **Better Tactics and Training:** In 1000CE, most armies were not very well organized.  They were generally a combination of mercenaries who had very little loyalty to thier generals and were quick to break and run, peasants who often received no more than 2 weeks of training, and a small minority of knights who were individually well trained and disciplined, but spent very little time actually training to fight as a group.  By 1500CE we saw a re-emergence of professional armies.  Mercenaries and peasants were largely replaced by career soldiers.  Men who would spend months or years training to fight together.  This made a huge difference in unit cohesion.  You also saw deliberately mixed arms formations emerge, like pike blocks interspersed with halberds or greatswords in well thought out proportions.
- **Better Castles:** In 1000CE, most castles were simple wooden forts or keeps.  These fortifications often had significant blind spots, limited capacity, an were relatively easy to take once breached.  By 1500CE, castles were much bigger and more thought out.  Walls and gate houses had machicolations to allow archers to fire straight down through gaps at the enemy even after that got all the way to the wall.  Castles had inner fortifications designed to surround enemy troops after the primary defenses were taken, and if necessary they could fall back to secondary inner keep that were basically castles inside of the main castle.

### So why does any of this matter?

The magic civilization knows magic.  They are good at it, they are proud of it.  If they want to do better, the most logical path is better magic, not this unknown, untested science things that they don't really know how to properly exploit anyway.

Likewise, the craftsmanship civilization will not turn to science for all the same reasons.  From thier perspective, science is as unknown and untested as it is to the magic civilization. They don't turn to it because they know it would take generations before they could figure out science well enough to compete with good old fashion hard work and experience.  So, instead of wasting time turning to science, they will turn to what they know.  Work harder, pay more attention to detail, and take pride in your work, and you can make the weapons and fortifications you need to win the war.  And unlike science, better craftsmanship can be achieved now, in this generation when you need it most.

Answer (score 2):

**Bureaucracy and religion.**

Everything is done according to proscribed standards. Procedure becomes ritual, habits dominate, every spare moment is take-up with prayer and incantation allowing no room for creative or de-facto subversive thought (reasoning beyond the allowed limits).

Politeness and social ritual dominate every encounter, ceremonies of greeting, eating and parting ensure that no nasty surprises are able to intrude on the perfect peace of every moment.

Beware:

Don't go to war with neighbouring states. Wars tend to create chaos, an enemy to the order of your perfectly tranquil society. They also demand changes in tactics and technology in response to enemy aggression - that's likely to destabilise society. Best to be isolationist, cut-off from the maelstrom of disorder that's the rest of the world.

Answer (score 1):

**The ruling class blocks the development of technology that undermines their power, at the expense of society as a whole**

The ruling classes in your nonmagical societies have the foresight to suppress advancements that could threaten their dominance. It's in their short sighted interest to do so, but the cumulative effect over the centuries is to slow technological advancement to a crawl.

Some real world examples:

- In feudal Japan, the  samurai attempted to suppress firearms because they rendered their chief function obsolete. The samurai had political power and used it to suppress technology that threatened their own ascendancy, even though it made the country as a whole less militarily powerful.
- The printing press has been an immense benefit to human knowledge, but if the Catholic church had anticipated that printed books would enable the protestant reformation, they would have suppressed that as hard as they could.

Magic users might even try to deliberately encourage this, perhaps giving political leaders accurate visions of a future where a new technology leads to their downfall.